# Align Players Rotation

Tags: rotation, vector, unreal

I'm currently working on rope Swinging.
The Rope consists of Physics Constraints/Joints and between them the rope is rendered.

I would like align my Character's Pitch to the Rope.

I'm horribly bad at vector Math, and I have trouble finding the solution.
Here's a picture that shows what I want to achieve:
[image]

I tried using the Difference between two joints but somehow it doesn't work.

I'm using Unreal Engine if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you make an object rotate to face a vector with a rotator.

So in this case you want your player's Z (Unreal's up) to face the vector between the two points on the rope it's touching.

So if we get the two nearest points on the rope (p1 and p2 for ex):
[image]

If we do (p2-p1) and normalize it, we get the direction we want the player to turn.

Then we can use a Rotator to orient the player to that vector. In this case we want to make a Rotator from a known Z axis (The vector we just found).

And then we apply the rotator we get from that on the player.

[image]

If you want to set the forward direction too, there's a "Make Rot from ZX" that will try to orient the player to meet those two vectors.

There's a Rotator class with these functions in C++ if you're using that.

(BTW some engines like Unity just let you set the up vector of your player explicitally like "player.transform.up = ropePitch" or something)

(I could also probably explain the math going on in the background but for practical use this is all you need!)

Comment: How can I do an equivalent (specifically something like "Make Rot from ZX" from C++? (I'm trying to align a mesh to a surface normal)